# Is there a way to check where R is 'stuck' within a for loop? (R)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am using `system()` to run several files iteratively through a program via CMD. It deposits each outputs into a sub-directory designated for specifically and only that input file. So # of inputs is exactly equal to the number of output directories/outputs.

My code works for the first iteration, but I can see in the console that it won't move on to the second file after completing the first. The stop sign remains active so I know R is still 'running', but since the for loop environment is unique I can't really tell what it's stuck on. It just stays like this for hours. Therefore I'm not sure how to begin to diagnose the issue I'm having. Is there a way of tracing what happened after cancelling the code, for example?

If your curious, the code looks like this btw. I don't know how to make it reproducible, so I just commented each line:

```
for (i in 1:length(flist)) {
##flist is a vector of character strings. Each 
row of characters is both the name of the input file and the name of the 
output directory

  setwd(paste0(solutions_dir, "\\", flist[i])) 
  #sets the appropriate dir

  system(paste0(program_dir,"\\program.exe I=", 
  file_dir, "\\", flist[i], " O=",solutions_dir, "\\", flist[i], 
  "\\solv")) 
  ##line that inputs program's exe file and the appropriate input/output 
  locations


}
```

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.0/topics/timeout

Comment: Does the code exit the `for` block after the first iteration, or does it simply hang at the ending `}` line of the `for` block after iterating once?

Comment: It exits the block after iteration 1 and then starts again with [2] from the top. It changes the directory at the start of each new iteration so that the results are posted in the right sub-directory.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not clear that changing the timeout for internet operations will help here

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Not a generic timeout.

Comment: The easiest way, is to just add a bunch of `print("part 1");print(i)` statements (for each part), then go through your outputs. Read this for how to make it reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve